# Page Break is splitting in the middle of a single row in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, page-splits, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report for an Invoice and it generally works perfectly but occasionally it will page break in the middle of a row in the main Tablix. The row will split and leave part of the text on one page and the rest on the next. The Tablix has no inherent page breaking. I was just relying on it to break between rows (regardless of which rows). There are a couple rows that repeat on each page. There is a second Tablix below the Detail one with Summary Totals. This is just some background info about the report. I'm relatively new to SSRS and haven't had the greatest luck with the formatting thus far.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

@matt you might want to adjust the tablix or row KeepTogether property. This affects how it tries to have all rows/table on the same page.

Comment: Travis, I looked through all the rows and tablix settings and adjusted the KeepTogether property but still ended with the same result.  Have you dealt with reports with open-ended tablix's (no page breaking) that overcame this issue before?  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Matt I had the same issue before. In my case, adjusting the KeepTogether property appropriately address the unintended rows/groups/tables split into different page of the report. One thing I want to point out is, it usually happen with report that involves multiple groups or tables, as oppose to only one big table.

Comment: @Matt I just noticed the SQL 2012 RTM CU8 and SQL 2012 SP1 CU4 fixes the KeepTogether for SSRS 2012. I am not sure it applies in your case, just thought you may need to be aware of that. Here is the KB link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2832818

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem however mine was that the page break was at the wrong place and thus messed up with my report.

How I ended up solving it was to get an estimate on how many rows I can fit on a page and than using the NTILE() SQL function to divide the results into multiple pages by adding a "page number" to the resultset.

Than I've set the field to be used a s a parrent row group and forced a page break after each group. It's not perfect but it worked out for me.

Note that you *may* have to resort to using a cursor to solve the page breaks.